# Exclude URI in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Can anyone please tell me why this isn't working?

I've tried variations of Request_URI, like %{REQUEST_URI}. I've tried different regexes, and I've tried putting the setenv inside the files section, but none have worked.

```
RewriteEngine On

SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/support/ REDIRECT_noauth=1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/other
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]


<Files "index.php">
  AuthUserFile *****/.htpasswd
  AuthGroupFile /dev/null
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Login"

  Order Deny,Allow
  Satisfy any
  Deny from all
  Allow from env=REDIRECT_noauth
  Require valid-user
</Files>
```

Thanks!

Comment: is `RewriteEngine on` set on top ?

Comment: Yes, it's set on top.

Comment: But you haven't written your requirements yet. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear. I want to bypass login for the support page only.

Comment: Almost six years late, but I’ve [identified the underlying problem](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/httpd-subrequest-variable-inconsistencies.html). mod_rewrite fulfills requests using subrequests. SetEnvIf doesn’t inherit the REQUEST_URI variable for subrequests. You’re effectively doing: `SetEnvIf "\0" ^/support/ REDIRECT_noauth=1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/support/ REDIRECT_noauth

AuthUserFile *****/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login"

Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from all
Allow from env=REDIRECT_noauth
Require valid-user
```

Comment: Still doesn't work...I see [access_compat:error] in the error log, specifically AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /path/index.php (when I removed the files directive, it's now client denied by server configuration: /path/support/ though support doesn't exist in that context)

Comment: What URI do you see in your browser when it doesn't work? Also if your .htaccess has more code then show in your question.

Comment: The URI converts from /support/ to /support, and the login prompt comes up. I've tried the config with ^/support also and no go.

Comment: `The URI converts from /support/ to /support` How is this happening since there is no rule in my answer doing this. I suggested before **if your .htaccess has more code then show in your question**

Comment: I've updated the original question with the rest of the file.

Comment: Ok is `/support/` a valid directory and does `/support/` also have .htaccess in it?

Comment: No, slim framework is handling routing. support is one of the defined routes.